# Which conjecture has remained unsolved the longest?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, open-problem

This is not so much a question as a mathematical discussion.

**Which conjecture/postulate/hypothesis in mathematics has remained unsolved for the longest?**

Fermat's Last Theorem springs to mind but that was solved in the 90's by Andrew Wiles.

Comment: Probably twin primes or odd perfect numbers. Related:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27075/what-is-the-oldest-open-problem-in-mathematics

Comment: Not sure if it really is a conjecture, but it has supposedly been *felt* for a long time that the parallel axiom is ugly and *should* be a consequence of the rest. That might be a conjecture that had existed for millenia before it was settled.

Comment: Which integers can occur as the area of right triangles with rational sides?

Comment: I would mention the **squaring the circle** problem, which was considered by ancient Greeks. It remained open for at least 2,500 years before being completely solved in 1882 by Ferdinand von Lindemann, who famously proved the transcendency of $\pi$.

Comment: But the question seems to ask about an open conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

The best method for [tetrahedra packing](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/08/30/tetrahedra-packing/) dates back at least 2500 years. The packing density of .856347, discovered in 2010, hasn't been proven the best possible.